# Generate random numbers in a random number of rows using sed

Tags: random, sed, numbers, rows

How to generate random numbers (lenght of 1 row max 5 fields) in a random number of rows (but no more than 150 rows) using sed? Is it possible or better use Perl for this?

Comment: Why do you want to use `sed` ? `Perl` or even a `shell script` will do the job, but I don't see the use case for `sed` here

Comment: Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem. Also, include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `sed` is the tool for this, but if you want to generate random numbers on random rows on `unix`, something like this would do:

```
od -An -t d2 -w10 /dev/urandom | head -n $(( RANDOM % 150 ))
```

Note: these are signed 16 bit numbers, update `-t` and `-w` to change that.

**od options**

- `-An`   don't output address.
- `-t d2` output 2 byte numbers and convert to decimal.
- `-w10`  number of fields multiplied by byte length.

**perl solution**

Use `int rand(n)` to get a random integer number from 0 up to n (see `perldoc -f rand`).

```
for ( 1 .. int rand(150) ) {
    print int rand(10), " " for (1 .. 5);            
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: what if you have only sed or perl in your disposal?

Answer (score 0):

sed is about parsing and editing existing text streams, not really generating them. Almost any programming language (including perl) would be better suited to the task.

Comment: I have only sed and perl to my disposal. How to do this using perl?